# Didn't use any particular sizes in android layout but still mobile view is entirely different than emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my xml what I am using currently...

In this xml I almost use the wrap content and match parent.

I can set the listview height according to my emulator. In emulator it shows perfectly and view is also looking perfect. But while coming to the mobile view which was updated here is not looking not same as emulator.

Here my emulator and my mobile sizes are entirely different how can I sent according to my mobile size? In mobile it shows space at bottom but not in emulator.

Can any one please help me how to set according to my mobile size? If I view the same code in the large emulator it same look as big size mobile view. 
If I change the sizes it varies for small size mobiles so how can I over come these problem? Is it possible to view all the mobile views same?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/cheflist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp" 
            android:divider="#778899"
            android:dividerHeight="1sp">
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/footer" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/cheflist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[This is my mobile view it shows space at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIF3Z.png)

Comment: wat looka are you expecting ? you want entire screen to be occupied with list view and at bottom with relative view ? plz clarify

Comment: Try to fix the size for bottom layout and make your listview height matchparent.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eIF3Z.png

Comment: Iw ant to show both list view and the footer also.. But i dnt want any space which was showed in image..

Comment: @yamuna if number of items in the listview are less then how you want???

Comment: @kalyanpvs did u see my image? Is ir proper thats my problem..?

Comment: @yamuna posted my answer check like that

Comment: @kalyanpvs If i fix the sizes for bottom layout it looks good for one mobile and bootom layout invisible for small size mobiles...?

Comment: @yamuna it wont invisible for small mobiles it will visible for all mobiles.if your bottom layout has some equal height of all views then you can make it wrap_content also

Answer (score 0):

Just change the height of ListView to "match_parrent", It will solve your problem.

Comment: Second RelativeLayout height needs to be "wrap_content".

Comment: already second layout height was wrap_content but still not appearing

Comment: Ok I think your problem is   "android:layout_below="@+id/cheflist" " this line. Remove it and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
// make sure footer layout view have width match_parent and height wrap_content
        <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cheflist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:divider="#778899"
        android:dividerHeight="1sp" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cheflist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#778899"
    android:dividerHeight="1sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Replace the above code with previous code and let me know.

Comment: second layout displays nothing..it moves outside

Comment: Can you please send this layout="@layout/footer"?

Comment: Yes Please paste asap. :)

Comment: Its not supporting that much of characters

Comment: Ok try to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.